# How do I share a password in a FIPS-compliant manner?

Tags: passwords, fips

This is a really basic question, but I'm a newbie in security.  What I'm wondering is: How do I share a password for an encrypted document in a FIPS 140-2 compliant manner?  That is, say I have a PDF, DocumentA, encrypted with AES-128 using a password. I want to share DocumentA with Bob, via e-mail.  I e-mail Bob DocumentA - now how do I give him the password?

This is a situation that would come up quite frequently, so calling to verbally give him the password each time would not be convenient.  Obviously including the password in the e-mail itself is a terrible idea and defeats the purpose of encryption.

I've read the FIPS documentation from NIST ([here](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/140/2/final)), and the associated annexes A-D (available at the same link) and haven't been able to find any information on this rather crucial part.

Can anyone point me to the documentation that states this?  Thanks so much.

Comment: What speaks against Public-Privat-Key Encryption instead of Symmetric Encryption? eg. PGP for Email

Comment: @Serverfrog - The only thing against it is that I'm having trouble understanding how the public key are made public.  I'm trying to wrap my brain around Certificate Authorities.

Comment: @ElizaBennet How exactly is compliance with FIPS 140-2 important here? What security level is your environment in? FIPS compliance isn't just met by choosing controls from the annexes. ;)

Comment: @TomK.Well, we're working on documenting complete compliance with the U.S. government's CUI rules ([NIST SP 800-171](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-171/rev-1/final)).  Since the documents are kind of low on specifics, I figured that choosing FIPS compliant encryption would be ideal, because their own standards have to be good enough.

Comment: For instance, one part (3.13.8) says to "Implement cryptographic mechanisms to prevent unauthorized disclosure of CUI during transmission unless otherwise protected by alternative physical safeguards." - I was planning on ensuring our cryptographic methods are FIPS-compliant in order to fully check that box off.  As of now, we use secure file transfer systems, but I want to establish a policy in case secure file transfers aren't available for some reason.

Comment: Is Bob always the same Bob, or are you sending documents to different people. If it's just you and Bob, then agreeing on a password ahead of time would be the easiest way, and continually using that password.

Comment: Unfortunately there are different files to share with different users from Alice to... Zebra (I can't think of a Z name).  Otherwise you're right, it would be easiest to do that.

Comment: FIPS 140 does not talk about password sharing. Question cannot be answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **NEVER** send a password over e-mail, or similar way. You can solve that issue using [Public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) (*or asymmetrical cryptography*). I won't get into much detail about how it works but the basic idea is that everyone has a pair of keys, a public (*which should be **public***) and a private one (*which should be kept **secret***). The public key is used to encrypt messages and the private key to decrypt messages.

[image]

For example if Bob wants to send "info.pdf" to Alice, he will encrypt it with Alice's public key, which is known, and **only** Alice's private key can be used for the decryption (*only Alice knows the private key*). This of course is a very minimal example and public key cryptography is a huge topic, so you should definitely make your research on the subject.

Now there are many easy ways you can use to encrypt your e-mails, files etc... For example [**PGP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) is one of the most popular standards to use for email encryption that uses *symmetric-key cryptography* to encrypt the data and *public-key cryptography* to encrypt the key that was used to encrypt the data. Then the receiver uses his private key to decrypt the encrypted-key, and then uses the decrypted-key to decrypt the data. So [**PGP**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) uses both *symmetric-key cryptography* and *public-key cryptography*.

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer, because I don't understand the whole digital certificates/signatures field.  I'll do more research into that.  But what I don't understand is why FIPS approves of using password protection when you can't really use it...?

Comment: You have to know what to use in different circumstances. Also don't forget that *One Time Pad*, when is correctly used is unbreakable, but it just can't be used for everything!

Comment: Also the [**link**](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/fips/140/2/final) you posted also talks about "*cryptographic key management*" so I suppose it refers to *public key cryptography*.

Comment: Thanks for the edit with more details and the picture, that helps me get this concept straight!

Comment: @ElizaBennet You're Welcome! Also have in mind that **PGP** combines *symmetric-key cryptography* with *public-key cryptography*, so in this sense it also uses a password to encrypt the initial data but in order to safely transmit the key it uses *asymmetrical cryptography*. I also edited the answer to mention that.